# Is there a possibility to get the image from internet without calling API in swift?

Tags: json, swift, api, imageurl

I got the (*data* , *response* , *error*) already in completion handler from the first call to the **api**. And have to get the image from the links nested in the json object(which is parsed from the obtained data) . Do I need to create a separate method which will again call the **api** using the nested link of the json or is there any short hand (frame work) methods to do that. like ,

- let image = UIImage(data: imageData)                // default method in framework
- let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile : fileLocation)  // default method in framework

let image = UIImage(url: URL)        // expecting a method like this

I'm expecting a method like the above one which gets the image directly from the url without having call to the api repeatedly to get the images from the nested links. Is that possible, so that I can avoid multiple api calls and minimise threads?

Comment: Keeps the URLs in memory, use again `URLSession` on that specific image data, and then call `UIImage(data: imageData)` on it. Or use SDWebImage, Alamofire+Image, KingFisher...

Comment: `avoid multiple api calls and minimise threads` - do you see issues with the number of threads when using the recommended approach?

Answer (score 0):

Since the intoduction of the Combine framework it has become pretty comfortable to nest network calls.

This is an example with the `jsonplaceholder` API. The code first loads JSON containing an `id` and an `url`, then it loads the image at this URL

```
import Combine

struct Photo : Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id : Int
    let url : URL
}

var storage : AnyCancellable?

let baseURL = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/1")!
storage = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: baseURL)
    .map(\.data)
    .decode(type: Photo.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    .map(\.url)
    .flatMap { url in
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map(\.data)
            .replaceError(with: Data())
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink { result in
        print(result)
    } receiveValue: { imageData in
        print("Image successfully loaded containing", imageData)
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can display image from url as well without api call. to achieve this you need to convert url to Data

```
let imageURL = "https://picsum.photos/200/300"
let imageData = Data(contentsOf: URL(string: imageURL)!)
let finalImage = UIImage(data: imageData)




 extension UIImageView {
        func load(imageURL: URL) {
            DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
               let imageData = Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
               let finalImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       //set your image here in main thread 
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

please try it and check if it works for you

Comment: You are strongly discouraged from loading data synchronously with `Data(contentsOf:)`. Don’t. It blocks the thread and causes bad user experience.

Comment: yes I agree and I'm not appreciating this approach but according to question I just want show this is achieveable

Comment: I have updated my answer can you please suggest will this approach be fine loading image synchronously?

Comment: It still blocks the thread, not the main thread but the common global thread. Loading data asynchronously with URLSession – either with conventional completion handler or with modern Combine publisher  –  is the state of the art.

Comment: but as far as I think this can be only by a api call?

Comment: Strictly spoken both `URLSession` and `Data(contentsOf` perform a kind of API call. With Combine you can chain multiple calls in a kind of synchronous appearance but asynchronous performance.

Comment: Please see my alternative suggestion.

Comment: I tried this without having extensions to UIImageView. It works for images with https protocol links but not with images of link http protocol.

Comment: you need to set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to true under NSAppTransportSecurity in info.plist in order to work https link

Comment: Yeah I forgot to set that. Even after setting that it is not loading the image. More over it is printing this error to the console:

Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIImageView setImage:]